# How to add an image to the top of div using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, image, html

I have an empty div which is draggable and to which I need to add an image to the left top corner And it should be able to move along with the div.

So how do I do that?

```
<div class="example">
<div>
```

This is the script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {

  $('.example').draggable

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    .example {
       position: relative;
    }
    .example .imghandle {
       position: absolute;
       height: 30px;
       width: 30px;
       top: -30px;
       left: -30px;
    }

<div class="example">
   <div class="imghandle"></div>
<div>
```

make the image a background of the div, or just put an `<img>` tag there and add the class

[here it is with :before](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/g6cdL/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Just put the image in the `<div>`, or to add it dynamically, `$('.example').append(image_handle)`. Or use `:before`

Comment: I love how we both assume it's a handle.

Comment: @Truth, before will only work if he makes it a background image. Then you will also have troubles with event handlers *if you so choose to attach them to the image*

Answer (score 1):

Top of div is prepend.

```
$('.example').prepend('<img src="" />');
```

Comment: First thanks for your reply but the image is not seen if I use prepend .